# Is there a way to pin the VS output window's "category" dropdown?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to prevent Visual studio from automatically switching the category in the Output window to "Build" every time I try to run my unit tests?

Usually that makes perfect sense; If I build, I usually want to see the output of the build.

But when I am running unit tests, what I want to see is the "Tests" category.  I have custom output going there which I cannot send to the Test Runner window.  But every single time that I run my tests, the Output window builds first and so switches over to "Build" and so I have to manually set it back.

(I realize I could prevent it from automatically building but let us assume for a moment I do not want to do that.  Besides, if I debug my unit tests, then it auto-switches to the Debug category and, I don't want that for unit tests either)

So is there some kind of "pin" button somewhere or some box I can temporarily uncheck to prevent the auto category switch from happening?

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to do this from what I can tell.